# How do I remove the hair, dust and gunk off of silicon putty/silicone earplugs?

Tags: cleaning

I want to continue to use my silicone earplugs, but they're becoming increasingly disgusting and laden with little particles. **Help!**

Comment: Honestly, if they're the soft shapeable putty kind, not solid, you're better off throwing them out and replacing them. They're extremely cheap and have a very limited lifespan. Just toss them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ear plugs are solid silicone, you can use a tiny bit (a drop or two) of mild dish washing liquid with warm (not hot) water to wash them by hand.

Here's how.

1. Wash your hands.
2. Mix the cleaning solution in a clean cup.
3. Soak the plugs in the liquid for a minute or five.
4. Work the yuck loose with your fingers gently massaging the plugs to get into every crevice.
5. Rinse with warm water thoroughly.
6. Set aside to dry on a clean surface.

Some ear plugs have a small spring-loaded insert that blocks the sound canal if there is an explosive sound. The small mechanism must be removed before the silicone earpiece is washed as above.

Answer (score 0):

When I had silicone orthotic earplugs made, the technician told me to gently wipe them with 75% rubbing alcohol to clean them. But these earplugs are fully cross-linked rubber, not putty. I'm not sure if there's any problem using alcohol on silicone putty.